# Range Slider not working in audio player ,JQuery,HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an mp3 player I built with jQuery ,in it Range slider not working in audio player. I tried the following code but it doesn't worked. I've tried lots of different code from different places but nothing seems to work. On Mozilla browser its working correctly but on chrome slider does not works. My latest attempt looks like this.

```
   let previous = document.querySelector('#pre');
let play = document.querySelector('#play');
let next = document.querySelector('#next');
let title = document.querySelector('#title');
let recent_volume = document.querySelector('#volume');
let volume_show = document.querySelector('#volume_show');
let slider = document.querySelector('#duration_slider');
let show_duration = document.querySelector('#show_duration');
let track_image = document.querySelector('#track_image');
let auto_play = document.querySelector('#auto');
let present = document.querySelector('#present');
let total = document.querySelector('#total');
let artist = document.querySelector('#artist');


let timer;
let autoplay = 0;

let index_no = 0;
let Playing_song = false;

//create a audio Element
let track = document.createElement('audio');


//All songs list
let All_song = [{
        name: "{{ $data->name }}",
        path: "{{ asset('assets/' . $data->file) }}",
        img: "/assets/images/quran.jpg",
        singer: "{{ $data->description }}"
    }

];


// All functions


// function load the track
function load_track(index_no) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    reset_slider();

    track.src = All_song[index_no].path;
    title.innerHTML = All_song[index_no].name;
    track_image.src = All_song[index_no].img;
    artist.innerHTML = All_song[index_no].singer;
    track.load();


    timer = setInterval(range_slider, 500); // update the range slider every 500 milliseconds
    total.innerHTML = All_song.length;
    present.innerHTML = index_no + 1;
}

load_track(index_no);


//mute sound function
function mute_sound() {
    track.volume = 0;
    volume.value = 0;
    volume_show.innerHTML = 0;
}


// checking.. the song is playing or not
function justplay() {
    if (Playing_song == false) {
        playsong();

    } else {
        pausesong();
    }
}


// reset song slider
function reset_slider() {
    slider.value = 0;
}

// play song
function playsong() {
    track.play();
    Playing_song = true;
    play.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}

//pause song
function pausesong() {
    track.pause();
    Playing_song = false;
    play.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}


// next song
function next_song() {
    if (index_no < All_song.length - 1) {
        index_no += 1;
        load_track(index_no);
        playsong();
    } else {
        index_no = 0;
        load_track(index_no);
        playsong();

    }
}


// previous song
function previous_song() {
    if (index_no > 0) {
        index_no -= 1;
        load_track(index_no);
        playsong();

    } else {
        index_no = All_song.length;
        load_track(index_no);
        playsong();
    }
}


// change volume
function volume_change() {
    volume_show.innerHTML = recent_volume.value;
    track.volume = recent_volume.value / 100;
}

// change slider position 
function change_duration() {
    slider_position = track.duration * (slider.value / 100);
    track.currentTime = slider_position;
    setInterval(range_slider, 1000); // update the range slider every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
}

// autoplay function
function autoplay_switch() {
    if (autoplay == 1) {
        autoplay = 0;
        auto_play.style.background = "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)";
    } else {
        autoplay = 1;
        auto_play.style.background = "#FF8A65";
    }
}


function range_slider() {
    let current_time = Math.floor(track.currentTime); // get the current time of the audio in seconds
    let duration = Math.floor(track.duration); // get the total duration of the audio in seconds
    let minutes = Math.floor(current_time / 60); // calculate the minutes for the current time
    let seconds = current_time % 60; // calculate the seconds for the current time
    let total_minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60); // calculate the minutes for the total duration
    let total_seconds = duration % 60; // calculate the seconds for the total duration

    // display the current time and total duration in the format "mm:ss"
    show_duration.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds} / ${total_minutes}:${total_seconds}`;

    // update the range slider to reflect the current time
    slider.value = (current_time / duration) * 100;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="duration">
       <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" 
                id="duration_slider"
                onchange="change_duration()">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the unnecessary variables minutes, seconds, total_minutes, and total_seconds by combining the calculation and assignment into one line.

```
function range_slider() {
    let current_time = Math.floor(track.currentTime);
    let duration = Math.floor(track.duration);
    show_duration.innerHTML = `${Math.floor(current_time / 60)}:${current_time % 60} / ${Math.floor(duration / 60)}:${duration % 60}`;
    slider.value = (current_time / duration) * 100;
    }
```